Do astronauts on the ISS use any sort of local 'currency', even in jest?
In prison, cigarettes might be considered a currency.   In grade school, maybe cookies.   On the ISS, do astronauts do any sort of bartering for chores for extra goodies or free time?
From my understanding, astronauts like spicy foods, so maybe folks who want extra spicy condiment packets might use them as a "currency."  They've got a lot of work to do, but do they ever do things like play poker or other such games where betting/wagering might come into play?
Might you ever hear, "I'll clean the ISS toilet for extra packets of Tabasco sauce!", even in a playful way?  A quick search turns up this bit:
"Peggy Whitson threatened to bar entry to the crew of the visiting shuttle Atlantis unless they came bearing a promised resupply of the spicy stuff..."
... so they do retain their sense of humor.

you might want to check Stuster's papers on astronaut journals; I have links in this answer to an unrelated question but I'm having trouble getting archive to work since the recent DDoS.

related: Is there any money in space?

That quote you mention does seem like it'd be some sort of "currency" even though it's trade. (In reality the ISS might be able to actually bar entry to a docking spacecraft but doing so would mean no resupply for the ISS and the craft has to go home way early. Personally, in that kind of environment where food and water have to be recycled/kept as safe as possible, I'm not gambling.)

I'll have to find the source video, which I saw years ago so will take some searching - but allegedly Russian rations of white cheese with nuts are so universally liked they are actually used as a currency on ISS.

@SF. links related to your cheese-with-nuts assertion.  Might be enough to make an answer out of even without finding the video, but I think it might be a video by Artemyev iNews urduPoint

...and no, hot sauces aren't sufficiently scarce to be a currency - they are such an essential, fundamental necessity the space agencies ensure there's no shortage of them.

@Erin found it! will make an answer tomorrow.

Ice cream is definitely highly coveted onboard (the frozen kind, not the freeze dried kind). I was on console for CRS-10 crew ingress. Almost immediately, the Dragon freezer telemetry started going crazy, registering each freezer door opening and closing in rapid succession. We finally figured out the crew was looking for ice cream, and had to call up and tell them there wasn't any room for ice cream on that flight. It's all temperature sensitive science experiments so please stop opening the freezer doors!

Russian astronaut Oleg Artemev says:

Now let's move on to desserts. Here we've got a cottage cheese.
This one is with nuts. It's the tastiest thing ever.
We use it as currency. Our partners, friends and colleagues astronauts,
Americans, Canadians, Europeans, Japanese very like it.
So we use it as a trade item, like a currency, its a real currency.
For cottage cheese we can trade anything. Shrimp, crawfish, the stuff we don't have

Erin linked a news article with the quote from Andrei Vednikov:

The commander always advises newcomers: order more cheese. And our cheese is really good, like currency, there is no such product in American cuisine. . Americans trade seafood, steaks, desserts with our astronauts.

